# Obtener productos más vendidos de un Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Estoy intentando obtener los X productos mas vendidos de un array, el array puede contener mas de 200 productos. la estructura del array es esta:

```
const productos = [
  {
    cantidadBulto: "12",
    categoria: "Bebidas",
    company: "Empresas Polar",
    descripcion: "",
    idProduct: "020dfc7c-6293-4ac9-8901-b92496d95aef",
    imageId: "7297edbe-7dea-40cc-91d3-03a7afc54bae",
    name: "Agua Minalba 1.5L",
    presentacion: "Bulto",
    price: "18.2",
    priceBulto: "18.2",
    stock: "5",
    ventas: "8",
  },
  {
    cantidadBulto: "20",
    categoria: "Viveres",
    company: "Grupo daz ",
    descripcion: "Azucar",
    idProduct: "05398dbc-ee1d-4533-94d4-629fb3e99a23",
    imageId: "9e09f00f-a16e-4a21-837d-96ea5a0e9c08",
    name: "Azúcar Montalbán 1kg",
    presentacion: "Bulto",
    price: "24",
    priceBulto: "24",
    stock: "10",
    ventas: "53",
  }
];
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy implementando esto en React Native, alguna manera de hacer lo que quiero con .map y .filter?.

Intente Traer los datos ya ordenados desde Firebase, pero no logre encontrar una query correcta.

El campo que hay que verificar se llama "ventas", mediante ese campo quiero obtener un nuevo array con los X mas vendidos.

Intente con esta opción:

```
var miArray = [];
const mayores = (arr, len) =>{
  arr
    .slice()
    .sort(function (a, b) {
      return b - a;
    })
    .splice(0, len)}

    const getLista = async () => {
      try {
        const q = query(collection(db, "products"), limit(8));
        /* const q = query(collection(db, "products"), limit(8)); */
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        const docs = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push({ ...doc.data() });
    });
    /* para mas comprados */
    const queryMasComprados = query(collection(db, "products"));
    /* const q = query(collection(db, "products"), limit(8)); */
    const snapshotFire = await getDocs(queryMasComprados);
    const docsMasComprados = [];
    snapshotFire.forEach((doc) => {
      docsMasComprados.push({ ...doc.data() });
      miArray.push(JSON.parse(doc.data().ventas));
    });

    setArray(mayores(miArray, 5));
    setProducts(docs);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: ¿Tú has intentado hacer algo? Recuerda que es altamente recomendable incluir un [mcve].

Comment: he tratado de hacer un array con el valor del campo ventas, pero a la hora de comparar me devuelve productos repetidos

Comment: Adjunta tu intento en tu pregunta y nosotros te ayudamos en resolver tu problema.

Comment: ya lo agrego amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no estás tan perdido.

No es neceario el primer `.slice()`. La función `.sort()` es correcta salvo que al estar trabajando con objetos (y no con números) tienes que especificar que quieres comparar las `.ventas` de cada producto. El último `.slice()` también es correcto ya que de ese modo solo extraes los productos requeridos.

Una cosa que agregaría es convertir la propedad `.ventas` a número, ya que veo que en tu ejemplo es un string. Si pudieras hacer que llegue como número y no como string desde Firebase, sería genial y podrías omitir este paso.

```js
const ventas = [{ ventas: "15" }, { ventas: 5 }, { ventas: 6 }, { ventas: 3 }, { ventas: 10 }, { ventas: 7 }, { ventas: "13" }]

const mayores = (arr, len) => {
  return arr
    .map(producto => { producto.ventas = Number(producto.ventas); return producto })
    .sort((productoA, productoB) => productoB.ventas - productoA.ventas)
    .splice(0, len)
}

console.log(mayores(ventas, 2))
```

No he trabajado con Firebase, pero de hecho creo que se puede hacer lo que quieres desde que traes los objetos y ahorrarte todo esto. De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=es-419):

> Puedes especificar el orden de clasificación para tus datos mediante `orderBy()` y, con `limit()`, puedes limitar la cantidad de documentos recuperados. Si especificas un `limit()`, el valor debe ser mayor o igual que cero.

Así que tu query debería incluir algo como `orderBy("ventas")` y `limit(n)`.

Comment: Ya lo implemento amigo, y les digo 

Comment: Listo!!!
Muchas Gracias a todos por su ayuda!!! ✌

Comment: Si te sirvió la información, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada haciendo clic en la palomita. O en su defecto, coloca la solución que usaste, ya que podría ser de ayuda para futuros visitantes. Saludos.